# Selecting multiple rows from multiple columns as one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union, where-clause

As the title says I'm trying to select rows from Passive, Q, W, E, R that are not empty into one column
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygj7q.png and here is what I've tried with no luck yet

```
SELECT (Passive + Q + W + E + R) AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina'
AND (
(Passive!='')
or(Q!='')
or(W!='')
or(E!='')
or(R!='')
)
```

It would be even better if I could incorporate it with my previous query that works fine that selects names of columns that are not empty

```
SELECT column_name 
                        from information_schema.columns, patches.champions
                        where 
                        table_name = 'champions'
                        AND ((column_name ='Passive' and Passive!='')
                        or (column_name='Q' and Q!='')
                        or (column_name='W' and W!='')
                        or (column_name='E' and E!='')
                        or (column_name='R' and R!='')

                        )

                         AND Patch_No = '0.02'
                        AND Champion = 'Katarina'
```

**EDIT** this query gave me the right results but in 1 row and I want the results to be in separate rows

```
SELECT CONCAT(Passive, Q, W, E, R) AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina'
AND (
(Passive!='')
or(Q!='')
or(W!='')
or(E!='')
or(R!='')
)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Or better yet try adding a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Passive AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina' AND 
      Passive IS NOT NULL AND Passive != ''
UNION 
SELECT Q AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina' AND 
      Q IS NOT NULL AND Q != ''
UNION 
SELECT W AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina' AND 
      W IS NOT NULL AND W != ''
UNION 
SELECT E AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina' AND 
      E IS NOT NULL AND E != ''
UNION 
SELECT R AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina' AND 
      R IS NOT NULL AND R != ''
```

Comment: It works fine, last quesion though is there any way to combine this query with the one I posted in question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1wYL7zub here is the code it would be nice If i didn't have to go through 2 loops which have the same amount of results. And also that seems weird that I have to go now bind for 'ssssssssss' and bind 10 variables which are the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT CONCAT(Passive, Q,  W, E,  R) AS spellchamps
FROM champions 
WHERE Patch_No='0.02' AND Champion = 'Katarina' 
AND '' NOT IN (Passive, Q, W, E, R)
```